# Swift right CustomColor class declaration

Tags: swift, enums

because of strange color solutions in swift i needed to make customcolor class. And i dont know am i doing right.

i have a class CustomColors()

and usage: `color = CustomColors().black` and works perfectly

but i want to make use like: `color = CustomColors(.Black)`

i cant do like this:

```
init(_ Color: Colors) 
{
  switch Colors
     case .Black
        return UIColor(r:255,g:255,b:255,a:255)
}
```

A lot of things i dont know. Can someone put me on right solution? Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just use an enum? I mean, why do you need a class for it?

Comment: ok, how to do with enums? i cant declare enums like  enum Color: UIColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of custom class you can use an UIColor extension with convenience initializer, as such:

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(color: Colors) {
        switch color {
        case .black:
            self.init(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        case .white:
            self.init(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

But I think its better if you pre-define your colors using `struct`'s static properties, as such:

```
struct Theme {
    static let colorOne = UIColor(red: 0.952941, green: 0.952941, blue: 0.952941, alpha: 1.0) // F3F3F3
    static let colorTwo = UIColor(red: 0.203922, green: 0.203922, blue: 0.203922, alpha: 1.0) // 343434
    // and so on...
}
```

**Usage**

```
UILabel().backgroundColor = Theme.colorOne
UILabel().textColor = Theme.colorTwo
```

Comment: Thanks!!! i did before with struct but didnt know that i need to add static to properties. I thought properties declared in struct is already static :D

Answer (score 0):

you can add extension to UIColor class with your custom colors:

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
    static var mediumTurquoise: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red:0.31, green:0.82, blue:0.8, alpha:1)
    }
}
```

please be sure that the value of RGB between 0.0 and 1.0.

you can user the custom color as `UIolor.mediumTurquoise`